# Entity Framework EDMX file size disproportional big (many megabytes)

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-4, edmx, devart

This morning I used the Entity Framework designer to update my model from the database to select a single table. Out of nothing thousands of lines of XML were added to **storage model** of the EDMX file which had grown from 244 KB to over 14 MB. However, little has changed in my database since the last time I updated my model. I rolled back the changes to the edmx and tried it multiple times, but no matter what I do (add a missing procedure, update an existing table), these lines are readded.

Some background information: I'm connecting to Oracle 11, using Entity Framework 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010 pro 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel.), and using the `Devart.Data.Oracle` (6.60.258.0) provider from Devart. The generated C# class doesn't seem to change though.

Here is (a tiny bit) of the XML that was added to the storage model of the EDMX:

```xml
<Function Name="APEX" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_ADMIN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="APEX_MIG_PROJECTS_UPDATE_UPD_MIG_REV_FORMS" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_MIG_PROJECTS_UPDATE.UPD_MIG_REV_FORMS" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_PROJECT_ID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DBID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORMID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_WORKSPACE_ID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SOURCE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SOURCE_SYNTAX" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SOURCE_STATUS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_MIG_PROJECTS_UPDATE_UPD_MIG_REV_REPORTS" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_MIG_PROJECTS_UPDATE.UPD_MIG_REV_REPORTS" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_PROJECT_ID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DBID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORTID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_WORKSPACE_ID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SOURCE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SOURCE_SYNTAX" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SOURCE_STATUS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_ADD_AD_COLUMN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.ADD_AD_COLUMN" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LABEL" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_HELP_TEXT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DEFAULT_VALUE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_DISPLAY_WIDTH" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_DISPLAY_HEIGHT" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_DATA_TYPE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORT_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORT_COL_ALIGNMENT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SYN_NAME1" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SYN_NAME2" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SYN_NAME3" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_ADD_AD_SYNONYM" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.ADD_AD_SYNONYM" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SYN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_DEL_AD_COLUMN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.DEL_AD_COLUMN" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_DEL_AD_SYNONYM" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.DEL_AD_SYNONYM" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_SYN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_DEL_COLUMN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.DEL_COLUMN" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_DEL_GROUP" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.DEL_GROUP" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_GROUP_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_DEL_TABLE" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.DEL_TABLE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_SYNCH_TABLE" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.SYNCH_TABLE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_AD_COLUMN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_AD_COLUMN" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_NEW_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LABEL" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_HELP_TEXT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DEFAULT_VALUE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_DISPLAY_WIDTH" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_DISPLAY_HEIGHT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_DATA_TYPE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORT_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORT_COL_ALIGNMENT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_AD_SYNONYM" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_AD_SYNONYM" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_SYN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_NEW_SYN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_COLUMN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_COLUMN" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_GROUP_ID" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LABEL" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_HELP_TEXT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_IN_FORM" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_SEQ_FORM" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_MASK_FORM" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DEFAULT_VALUE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REQUIRED" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_WIDTH" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_MAX_WIDTH" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_HEIGHT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_IN_REPORT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_SEQ_REPORT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_MASK_REPORT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_ALIGNMENT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_DISPLAY_IN_FORM" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_DISPLAY_IN_FORM" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_IN_FORM" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_DISPLAY_IN_REPORT" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_DISPLAY_IN_REPORT" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_IN_REPORT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_FORM_REGION_TITLE" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_FORM_REGION_TITLE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_REGION_TITLE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_GROUP" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_GROUP" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_GROUP_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_NEW_GROUP_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DESCRIPTION" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_SEQUENCE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_ITEM_DISPLAY_HEIGHT" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_ITEM_DISPLAY_HEIGHT" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_HEIGHT" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_ITEM_DISPLAY_WIDTH" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_ITEM_DISPLAY_WIDTH" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_DISPLAY_WIDTH" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_ITEM_FORMAT_MASK" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_ITEM_FORMAT_MASK" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_ITEM_HELP" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_ITEM_HELP" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_HELP_TEXT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_LABEL" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_LABEL" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LABEL" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_REPORT_ALIGNMENT" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_REPORT_ALIGNMENT" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORT_ALIGNMENT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_REPORT_FORMAT_MASK" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_REPORT_FORMAT_MASK" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COLUMN_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORMAT_MASK" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_REPORT_REGION_TITLE" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_REPORT_REGION_TITLE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORT_REGION_TITLE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE_UPD_TABLE" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEX_UI_DEFAULT_UPDATE.UPD_TABLE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_TABLE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_FORM_REGION_TITLE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_REPORT_REGION_TITLE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEXWS_FOLDER" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEXWS.FOLDER" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="I" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="S" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="U" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEXWS_HOME" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEXWS.HOME" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="S" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEXWS_PAGE" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEXWS.PAGE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="I" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="S" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEXWS_ROW" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEXWS.ROW" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="I" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="S" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="R" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEXWS_SEARCH" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEXWS.SEARCH" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="S" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="APEXWS_SHEET" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="APEXWS.SHEET" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="I" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="S" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="DEVELOPMENT_SERVICE_HOME" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="DEVELOPMENT_SERVICE_HOME_LOGIN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="DEVELOPMENT_SERVICE_SIGNUP" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="F" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SEP" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_TRACE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="C" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="PG_MIN_ROW" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="PG_MAX_ROWS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="PG_ROWS_FETCHED" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="FSP_REGION_ID" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="SUCCESS_MSG" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="NOTIFICATION_MSG" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="CS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="S" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="TZ" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LANG" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_TERRITORY" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_ADMIN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEM_EXISTS" ReturnType="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEM_EXISTS" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_ITEM_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_CURRENT_PAGE_IS_PUBLIC" ReturnType="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.CURRENT_PAGE_IS_PUBLIC" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_DEFINE_USER_SESSION" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.DEFINE_USER_SESSION" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_USER" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION_ID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_COOKIE_PROPS" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_COOKIE_PROPS" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_APP_ID" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COOKIE_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COOKIE_PATH" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_COOKIE_DOMAIN" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SECURE" Type="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Mode="Out" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_LDAP_PROPS" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_LDAP_PROPS" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_HOST" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_PORT" Type="decimal" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_USE_SSL" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_USE_EXACT_DN" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_DN" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SEARCH_FILTER" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_EDIT_FUNCTION" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="Out" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_NEXT_SESSION_ID" ReturnType="decimal" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_NEXT_SESSION_ID" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_SECURITY_GROUP_ID" ReturnType="decimal" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_SECURITY_GROUP_ID" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_SESSION_ID" ReturnType="decimal" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_SESSION_ID" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_SESSION_ID_FROM_COOKIE" ReturnType="decimal" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_SESSION_ID_FROM_COOKIE" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_USER" ReturnType="VARCHAR2" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_USER" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_GET_USERNAME" ReturnType="VARCHAR2" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.GET_USERNAME" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_IS_SESSION_VALID" ReturnType="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.IS_SESSION_VALID" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_LDAP_AUTHENTICATE" ReturnType="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.LDAP_AUTHENTICATE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_USERNAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_PASSWORD" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_HOST" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_PORT" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_USE_SSL" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_USE_EXACT_DN" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_STRING" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SEARCH_FILTER" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_LDAP_EDIT_FUNCTION" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_OWNER" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_LDAP_DNPREP" ReturnType="VARCHAR2" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.LDAP_DNPREP" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_USERNAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_LOGIN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGIN" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_UNAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_PASSWORD" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION_ID" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_APP_PAGE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_ENTRY_POINT" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_PRESERVE_CASE" Type="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_LOGOUT" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGOUT" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_THIS_APP" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_NEXT_APP_PAGE_SESS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_NEXT_URL" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_LOGOUT_THEN_GO_TO_PAGE" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGOUT_THEN_GO_TO_PAGE" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_ARGS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_LOGOUT_THEN_GO_TO_URL" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGOUT_THEN_GO_TO_URL" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_ARGS" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
</Function>
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_PORTAL_SSO_SENTRY_V1" ReturnType="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.PORTAL_SSO_SENTRY_V1" Schema="APEX_040000" />
<Function Name="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH_POST_LOGIN" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" StoreFunctionName="HTMLDB_CUSTOM_AUTH.POST_LOGIN" Schema="APEX_040000">
  <Parameter Name="P_UNAME" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_SESSION_ID" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_APP_PAGE" Type="VARCHAR2" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="P_PRESERVE_CASE" Type="PL/SQL BOOLEAN" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

UPDATE:

All those functions seem to be part of [Oracle Application Express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/overview/index.html), which is on my dev box for a long time, but this still doesn't explain why EF thinks it needs to add those functions all of a sudden.

What could be the cause of this XML bloat and how can I prevent Entity Framework from adding all this cra... stuff in the future?

Comment: Could you please specify the following:

1. The exact version (x.xx.xxx) of dotConnect for Oracle you are using. You can find the version of your current build in the Tools > Oracle > About menu of Visual Studio;
2. The exact version of your Visual Studio.

Comment: doConnect version 6.60.258.0 an Visual Studio version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel.

Comment: to clarify, are these various functions mentioned in the xml your functions or not?

Comment: No, they are certainly not. However, they are packages from another schema in that database. They are written by Oracle (they start with the text "Copyright (c) Oracle Corporation 2008. All Rights Reserved."), but I have no idea why they are suddenly included.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot reproduce the issue in our environment at the moment.

As an alternative, we recommend you to create and edit Entity Framework model with Entity Developer (the Devart Entity Model item in Visual Studio) because it is more adjusted to work with Oracle database than EDM Wizard.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, switching to the Devart designer is not an option (for now), since I will have to recreate the whole model and that is much more than simply loading it from the database (for instance, the model has other names for all properties and tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly. But I think you can choose which elements to Map on Entity Data Model Wizard.
[image: Entity Data Model Wizard Image]